# Trademark: software company with computer hardware shop

Tags: software, trademark

I thought of a business name, and bought the domain name for it (both .com and .net), and I plan to use it to for a software business online.
I then noticed a computer shop in the Philippines with the same name.
Could this be a trademark infringement?

Comment: What country are you in? Did they register a trademark in your country? Are you planning on doing business in their country?

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm British. The trademark is not registered in my country. My website will be for anyone in the world to use really.